# Installing Arch Linux with usb wifi?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Is it possible to install arch linux with my only internet coming from a wifi usb adapter? I am currently using a TP-Link Wireless N Nano USB Adapter Model No. TL-WN725N.

Whenever I try to use sudo wifi-menu or iwconfig, nothing helpful ever shows up. I am guessing that it can't read the usb wifi drivers. This is before partitioning and everything.

Is there a way install arch linux with a usb wifi adapter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install arch-linux through a wifi connection (USB or built-in wifi card) only if the wifi driver is supported by the linux kernel , In your case the  [`8188eu`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/8188eu-dkms/) isn't supported.

> Is there a way install arch linux with a usb wifi adapter?

You can use another USB ( e,g : USB with `ath9k_htc` , `rt2500usb` ... more [available here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers) ) .

The wifi card will be detected and configured easily through the `wifi-menu` command.